# awkコマンドについて

Tags: awk

下記の内容が記されたファイルにて `2 2 2 1 1 1` (この値は変動する)の先頭3つ `2 2 2` について2倍 (計算結果 `4 4 4 1 1 1` ) したい。どう表現すれば良いでしょうか？

```
&electrons
/
K_POINTS {automatic}
2 2 2 1 1 1
CELL_PARAMETERS {angstrom}
4.255648834196731  -2.457000000000000   0.000000000000000 
0.000000000000000   4.914000000000000   0.000000000000000 
0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   5.406000000000000 
ATOMIC_SPECIES
```

※ コメントの内容を反映

データを特定する条件は以下の通りです。

1. `K_POINTS`を含む行の次の行を対象とする
2. 対象となる行のスペースで区切られた6個の数値の内、最初の3個の数値を2倍にする

**変更前**

```
K_POINTS {automatic}
a a a b b b
```

**変更後**

```
K_POINTS {automatic}
2*a 2*a 2*a b b b
```

なお、上記のファイルは `SCF(Self-Consistent Field)`計算に用いる入力ファイルで、`K_POINTS` の書式は [Input File Description: K_POINTS automatic](http://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#idm1129) になります。

Comment: 対象となるデータを特定する条件は何でしょうか？①「先頭から４行目」、②「K_POINTSを含む行の次の行」、③「空白で区切られた6桁の数字列」や、④「条件に合う最初の行がだけが対象なのか、条件に該当するデータをすべて対象とするのか」などを明確にすると回答が得やすいと思います。

Comment: SCF(Self-Consistent Field)計算に用いる入力ファイルでしょうか？ そうであれば [K_POINTS](http://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#idm1129) のパラメーターを操作したい、という事が目的になりそうですね。

Comment: 例えば,6 6 6 1 1 1 なら、いくらにしたら、いいですか?12 12 12 1 1 1でいいですか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。データを特定する条件なのですが、①K_POINTSを含む行の次の行を対象②対象となった行の空白を含む数字6桁(a a a b b b)の頭3桁(a a a)に対して2倍したいです(2*a 2*a 2*a b b b)

Comment: ＠metropolis その通りです。

Comment: ＠mrrclb48z　その通りです。

Answer (score 0):

スクリプト例です。
K_POINTSを含む行をみつけたら、次の行を読み込み、最初の３個の数値を２倍して出力します。

```
awk ' {
    if(match($0, /K_POINTS/) != 0){             #K_POINTSを含む行
        print $0
        getline                                 #次の行を対象
        num = split($0, a)
        dlmt = ""
        for(no = 1; no <= num; no++){
            if( no <= 3){                       #最初の3行が対象
                printf("%s%d", dlmt, a[no]*2)   #値を2倍
            }
            else{
                printf("%s%d", dlmt, a[no])
            }
            dlmt = " "  #区切り記号を空白
        }
        printf("\n")
    }
    else{
        print $0
    }
}
'
```

Comment: 面倒くさい事をしていますね…。`/^K_POINTS/{print;getline;for(i=1;i<=3;i++) $i*=2; }{print}` で十分でしょう。

Comment: @metropolis より良い回答の案があるのであれば、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してください。